# Compiling VLCKit framework

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard, vlc

I'm following the directions on this page: http://wiki.videolan.org/Mac_OS_X_Framework

I can build the core components, but when I try to build framework I have an error

How can I fix it?

```
Build VLCKit of project VLCKit with configuration Debug

PhaseScriptExecution "Run Script" build/VLCKit.build/Debug/VLCKit.build/Script-EF78BD2E0CAEEF9500354E6E.sh
cd /Users/ragopor/vlc/projects/macosx/framework
/bin/sh -c /Users/ragopor/vlc/projects/macosx/framework/build/VLCKit.build/Debug/VLCKit.build/Script-EF78BD2E0CAEEF9500354E6E.sh

Building modules folder...
find: /Users/ragopor/vlc/projects/macosx/framework/build/vlc_build_dir/modules: No such file or directory
Removing module libmacosx_plugin.dylib
rm: /Users/ragopor/vlc/projects/macosx/framework/build/Debug/VLCKit.framework/Versions/A/modules/libmacosx_plugin.dylib: No such file or directory
Building library folder...
Building share folder...
Headers not needed for this product

Ld build/Debug/VLCKit.framework/Versions/A/VLCKit normal i386
cd /Users/ragopor/vlc/projects/macosx/framework
setenv MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 10.6
/Developer/usr/bin/llvm-gcc-4.2 -arch i386 -dynamiclib -isysroot /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk -L/Users/ragopor/vlc/projects/macosx/framework/build/Debug -L/Users/ragopor/vlc/projects/macosx/framework/build/Debug/VLCKit.framework/lib -F/Users/ragopor/vlc/projects/macosx/framework/build/Debug -filelist /Users/ragopor/vlc/projects/macosx/framework/build/VLCKit.build/Debug/VLCKit.build/Objects-normal/i386/VLCKit.LinkFileList -install_name @loader_path/../Frameworks/VLCKit.framework/Versions/A/VLCKit -mmacosx-version-min=10.6 -single_module -read_only_relocs suppress -lvlc -framework Cocoa -framework QuartzCore -single_module -compatibility_version 1 -current_version 1 -o /Users/ragopor/vlc/projects/macosx/framework/build/Debug/VLCKit.framework/Versions/A/VLCKit

ld: library not found for -lvlc
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
Command /Developer/usr/bin/llvm-gcc-4.2 failed with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe too late, but check [this out](https://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?f=32&p=222191)